# Migrating from JSF 2.2 to JSF 2.3

Tags: jsf, myfaces

I want to migrate from JSF 2.2 To JSF 2.3, the application was working fine when i have those two dependencies of JSF 2.2

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when i replaced them by those dependencies

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3-next-M3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3-next-M3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

i got an error saying

```
 No Factories configured for this Application
 A typical config looks like this;

<listener>
<listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener- 
class>
</listener>
```

Here is the Servlet Registration Bean

```
    @Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean facesServlet() {
    FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.jsf");
    registration.setName("Faces Servlet");
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    registration.setMultipartConfig(new
            MultipartConfigElement((String) null));
    return registration;
}
```

The ServletContext Initilializer

```
    @Bean
public ServletContextInitializer servletContextInitializer() {
    return servletContext -> {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
        servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.FONT_AWESOME", Boolean.FALSE.toString());
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES", "/WEB-INF/primefaces-california.taglib.xml");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.THEME", "california-#{guestPreferences.theme}");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE", "PRODUCTION");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD", "server");

    };
}
```

And iam using Tomcat server

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I tried to add the StartupServletContextListener in web.xml but nothing happens

Comment: I would try 2.3, not 2.3-next as this is a completely new codebase

Comment: i'm getting the same problem when using 2.3

Comment: then i can just suggest to try joinfaces - JSF 2.3 is also based on CDI and joinfaces handles this integration nicely

Comment: Iam already using join faces                                                                                                            
     <parent>
        <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>joinfaces-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.3</version>
    </parent>